# What is the best way to test at runtime whether .NET Core application is running on Windows or Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, windows, .net-core, .net-standard

What is the best way to test at runtime whether the application is running on Windows or Linux, with .NET Core 2.0 ?

Imagine for instance I've got a .NET Core application deployed on both Windows and Linux machines, and it needs to access local resources stored in files. Obviously, the path (and path format) to those files will be different, so what would be the best way to go about it?

Comment: Or this one, if the above doesn't work in .net core: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-determine-operating-c90d351b

Answer (score 0):

You can check `System.Environment.OSVersion.Platform` property.